# Initialize C array at definition depending on runtime input

Tags: c, array

Best way to initialize `rr` and `cc` depending on cycle number to pre-defined values in `r` and `c`.

```
int func(int cycle, int index, int i) {
  char *rr;
  char *cc;

  if (cycle % 2 == 0) {
      char r[4] = { 0, -1, 0, 1 };
      char c[4] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };
      rr = r;
      cc = c;
  }
  else {
      char r[4] = { -1, -1, 1, 1 };
      char c[4] = { 1, -1, -1, 1 };
      rr = r;
      cc = c;
  }

  return(index + rr[i] + cc[i]);
}
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, but my use case requires C arrays, I have updated the title

Comment: The code shown does not show effect before cause. It does show runtime selection between multiple arrays initialised at declaration, *with a **very** questionable scope*: Please show the intended use.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code, this is not even a complete function?

Comment: updated based on input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>This code is not correct. The `r[4]` and `c[4]` arrays you have are stored on the stack, which means that as soon as they go out of scope the data is no longer valid and you get undefined behavior because `rr` and `cc` now point to unused (and possibly overwritten) areas on the stack.</strike>

If you wanted to do this correctly, you could ensure that the arrays are kept alive either by storing on the heap, static memory, or high enough on the stack that they will live as long as `rr` and `cc` are used.

After reading it again, I realized I made a mistake. While the temporary `r` and `c` arrays are initialized in their own scopes that are immediately exited, the arrays themselves live on the same stack with the rest of the function. Still, it's definitely a bad habit to have use variables after they've left the scope even if they're technically still on the stack, so I would make the same changes anyway.

For example, you could do:

```
// Somewhere in a high enough scope (possibly the current one) or static
char r_1[4] = { 0, -1, 0, 1 };
char c_1[4] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };

char r_2[4] = { -1, -1, 1, 1 };
char c_2[4] = { 1, -1, -1, 1 };

// In the current scope
char *rr;
char *cc;

if (cycle % 2 == 0) {
  rr = r_1;
  cc = c_1;
}
else {
  rr = r_2;
  cc = c_2;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I did not realize that. For some reason it runs as expected without errors (billions of cycles), but this is compiled to run on GPU so maybe there is a slight difference how static memory is handled?

Comment: I was a bit wrong in my first post, see the update. Basically, as long as you don't use the rr and cc pointers after leaving this function, your original code is functionally correct. Still, I would make the changes because otherwise it looks pretty weird. Also, is this in CUDA? I'm not entirely sure if it would be handled differently there, but I suspect it would work the same as running on a CPU.

Comment: CUDA and yes, all use is in scope, but my code is definitely uglier! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good. Just an FYI, but your original code worked because arrays leaving scope without leaving the stack frame doesn't destroy them. However, if you did this with an object like a vector, it would call the destructor and wouldn't end up working.